# Is Spring Retry Template Thread Safe

Tags: java, spring

How do spring Retry Template work without @Component annotation present on that class I am able to @Autowired - how the autowiring is working for the same ? Is it thread-safe, because for me thread safety isn't working in same

Comment: You question title having `RestTemplate` but in the question you wrote **retry template**. Could you make it clear and edit?

Answer (score 0):

This class is thread-safe and suitable for concurrent access when executing operations and when performing configuration changes.
As such, it is possible to change the number of retries on the fly, as well as the BackOffPolicy used and no in progress retryable operations will be affected.